# Как сделать изменение фона сайта на пользовательскую картинку?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Если использовать AJAX и отправлять картинку на сервер, то возникает две проблемы:

1. Этот фон ставится для всех.
2. Сервер маленький и слабый, большой нагрузки не выдержит.

Вопрос вот в чём: "Как реализовать смену фона страницы на стороне клиента?"

Comment: каким образом картинку от клиента получаете?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример реализации на JS.

HTML

```
<input type='file' id='getval' />
```

CSS

```
body {
    background-image:url('');
    background-size:cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```

JS

```
document.getElementById('getval').addEventListener('change', readURL, true);
function readURL(){
    var file = document.getElementById("getval").files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function(){
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + reader.result + ")";        
    }
    if(file){
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }else{
    }
}
```

Демо:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vGJwom

Изображение можно запомнить на клиенте и не нагружать сервер.